# iOS Charts to make Stacked BarChart with 2 arrays

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts, stacked-chart

Well, I'm trying to make Stacked Bar Charts. (Swift, iOS-Charts from cocoapod.) under those conditions..

1. **I have 1 String Arrays and 2 Double Arrays:**

   1) `monthArray = {"1","2","3".....,"12"} //for xAxis Label`

   2) `finalBorrowArray = {0,0,500.0,0,200.0...etc}`

   3) `finalLendArray = {0,0,500.0,800.0,...etc}`
2. **Here's some Swift Code :**

   ```
   func setChartData(count:Int, range:UINT32) {

         var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
         var dataEntries2: [ChartDataEntry] = []

         for i in 0..<finalBorrowArray.count {

             let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: 
             [finalBorrowArray[i]])
             dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
         }

         for i in 0..<finalLendArray.count {

             let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: 
             [finalLendArray[i]])
            dataEntries2.append(dataEntry)
         }

         let yVals = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BarChartDataEntry in

             @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@PROBLEM@@@@@@@@@HELP@@@@@@@@@@@@@
             return ?
         }

         }

   let set = BarChartDataSet(values:yVals, label: "")
   set.drawIconsEnabled = false
   set.colors = [ChartColorTemplates.pastel()[0], ChartColorTemplates.pastel()[3]]

   set.stackLabels = ["(+)", "(-)"]

   let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)
   data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: 20))
   data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))
   data.setValueTextColor(.black)

   barChart.fitBars = true
   barChart.data = data
   ```

So What I think is I have to get `yVal` as `BarChartDataEntry` 
in let yVals. (Maybe..?)

But I have no idea How to get ovals with 2 `yAxis`... Any Help or Idea?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself..

I used another `BarChartDataEntry` which 2 arrays are combined, not use `yVals`.

**Here is the code:**

```
var finalEntries : [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<finalLendArray.count {

        let Entry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: [finalBorrowArray[i], finalLendArray[i]])
        finalEntries.append(Entry)
    }

    let set = BarChartDataSet(values:finalEntries, label: "")
```